# print page generation time

Tags: python, django

how would I print the time it took to render a page to the bottom of my site in django? i'm not sure of the application flow of django, so I don't know how this would work.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar), which includes a request timer and lots of other useful info for debugging things like this.

Comment: Oh. Really? Why do your users want to know how long it took to generate the page? ... I guess you want [digivampire's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10098487/344821) with the context manager, then.

Comment: i always thought the websites that showed their page being rendered in 0.1**** seconds made it seem cooler, so I guess I just want it for looks. :p

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your view handler, save the current date/time in a variable say `time_start` and pass that to the template context which renders the page.

Then define a custom template filter that will create `timedelta` based on `datetime.now()` value and the original datetime passed in as a parameter like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_elapsed(time_start):
    return str(datetime.now() - time_start)
```

Then in your template, simply display:

```
...
{{ time_start|get_elapsed }}
...
```

Comment: is there a way to do this globally? do I don't have to add it to every view function?

Comment: The template piece would go to your base template which you would inherit for all of your pages. As for the `time_start` easiest thing to do would be to wrap all views in a decorator that sets `time_start` in the default provided context for that view. Then you would simply apply it in front of every view (since you want the time difference between when the view started executing and when the templating is almost done).

Comment: You could also use a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) instead of using a decorator on every view.